# Program cannot find symbol in one of my method

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that adds a word, including it meaning, and deletes the word. In other words, a dictionary. I'm having problem with this particular method.

```
public void insert(WordMeaning w1) {
    WordMeaningNode current = list;
    WordMeaningNode back = null;
    WordMeaningNode temp = new WordMeaningNode(w1);

    try {

        boolean found = false;

        while (current != null && !found) {

            if (temp.w1.getWord().compareToIgnoreCase(current.w1.getWord()) <= 0) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                back = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        temp.setNode(current);

        if (back == null) {
            list = temp;
        } else {
            back.setNode(temp);
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
```

Now everything works fine minus the fact the method isn't detecting "w1" on line "if (temp.w1....)" and beyond. WordMeaning w1 calls up on two string that gives the name of the word and its definition.

My first thought was I placed WordMeaningNode temp where w1 cannot be detected, but I'm no longer sure.

Comment: You might have to post your `WordMeaningNode` class. Does it contain an attribute named `w1`?
`temp.w1` will search for a `w1` field in `WordMeaningNode` (declared class of `temp`). If you want to access the parameter of hte method, it is just `w1`. Thus, comparison will always compare the same word received from `getWord()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that WordMeaningNode doesn't have a member called `w1`.

Where you've got `w1`, swap that for the name of the member (of the `WordMeaningNode`) with the type `WordMeaning`.

So if your class is:

```
public class WordMeaningNode {

    public WordMeaningNode(WordMeaning meaning) {
        this.meaning = meaning;

    public WordMeaning meaning;

}
```

You should put:

```
temp.meaning.getWord().compareToIgnoreCase(current.meaning.getWord()) <= 0
//   -------                                       -------
```

The name of the variable you pass into the constructor is irelevant.